# Association property in DomainCollectionView and WCF RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, model-associations

I have a association in my poco class, ex:

```
public class Category() {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* HERE */
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}

public class Book() {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use MVVM patern, MVVM Light and RIA Services Toolkit. My Domain Service implementation contains a method GetCategories that include their books, ex:

```
public IQueriable<Category> GetCategories()
{
    return Model.Categories.Include("Books").OrderBy(pCategory => pCategory.Name);
}
```

In my ViewModel I have a DomainCollectionView that load GetGruposQuery. I also have a property for bind a grid and other controls, like:

```
public ICollectionView CollectionViewCategories {
    get { return myDomainCollectionViewCategories;}
}
```

I need get a child property CollectionView.Books for bind my controls and ADD, REMOVE itens in view, but this property is only EntityCollection and isn't a DomainCollectionView that contains methods for ADD, REMOVE, etc.

How I can get the current Books property (of CollectionViewCategories) as DomainCollectionView in my ViewModel?

Thank you!

---

I solve this question with: (CollectionViewCategories.CurrentItem as Category).Books.Remove(CollectionViewBooks.CurrentItem as Book)

```
private ICollectionView CreateView(Object source)
{
    CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
    cvs.Source = source;
    return cvs.View;            
}
//...
//After CollectionViewCategories loaded:
CollectionViewCategories.CurrentChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (CollectionViewCategories.CurrentItem != null)     
    {
        CollectionViewBooks = CreateView(fContext.Categories.Where(p => p.Id == (CollectionViewCategories.CurrentItem as Category).Id).FirstOrDefault().Books);
    }
    else
    {
        CollectionViewBooks = null;
    }
    RaisePropertyChanged("CollectionViewBooks");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need it ? EntityCollection do have these methods (Add,Remove...)
If you obtain an error while invoking them, it could lead to the fact that the Book class is not fully exposed to the client (lack of insert/update/delete methods on the domainservice)
Just to clarify, DomainCollectionView  is inteded to wrap an EntityCollection primarily for better dealing with MVVM and binding in general (see this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/12/02/introducing-an-mvvm-friendly-domaindatasource-the-domaincollectionview.aspx))

Comment: I need a way to create methods in child association (of Books) to AddNew, Remove, Edit, etc. But, these methods access only parent collection (of Categories).

Comment: Ok, you can't easily create methods on the association, but "Add" and "Remove" are already present. As far as Edit you don't need it 'cause the entity is directly editable. If you write something like collectionViewCategories.First().Books.Add(new Books()) do you get errors ?

Comment: In other words, I need another property of CollectionViewBooks as CollectionViewCategories' source.

Comment: Ok, so you can try CollectionViewBooks = new DomainCollectionView<Book>(myLoader, category.Books); Of course, myLoader is a CollectionViewLoader and category is an instance of a Category. <br/> BTW You don't need to use a collectionView in order to bind the Add/Remove command, I'm sure you know, but still I can't get the point of this question, so I can't help further